# Python Generate new columns based on string condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
| Fecha      | Partido                 | Equipo  |  xG  |  xGA |
|------------|-------------------------|---------|------|------|
| 2022-05-01 | América - Cruz Azul 0:0 | América | 1.53 | 0.45 |
| 2022-05-01 | Leon - América 2:0      | América | 1.70 | 0.35 |
```

I want to create three new columns based on the Partido column where the first team goes to a new column named Home, the second team to a column named Visitor and the score to a column named Score.

Desired Output:

```
| Fecha      | Partido                 | Equipo  |  xG  |  xGA | Home    | Away       | Score |
|------------|-------------------------|---------|------|------|-------- |------------|-------|
| 2022-05-01 | América - Cruz Azul 0:0 | América | 1.53 | 0.45 | América | Cruz Azul  | 0:0   |
| 2022-05-01 | Leon - América 2:0      | América | 1.70 | 0.35 | Leon    | América    | 2:0   |
```

I have tried splitting with delimiter but since some teams have two words in their names it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple using [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and a regex:

```
regex = r'([^-]+)\s*-\s*([^-]+) (\d+:\d+)'
df[['Home', 'Away', 'Score']] = df['Partido'].str.extract(regex)
```

output:

```
        Fecha                  Partido   Equipo    xG   xGA      Home       Away Score
0  2022-05-01  América - Cruz Azul 0:0  América  1.53  0.45  América   Cruz Azul   0:0
1  2022-05-01       Leon - América 2:0  América  1.70  0.35     Leon     América   2:0
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KFH5Sf/1)

If you don't want to modify the original DataFrame, you can also use named capturing groups to directly set the column names:

```
regex = r'(?P<Home>[^-]+)\s*-\s*(?P<Away>[^-]+) (?P<Score>\d+:\d+)'
df2 = df['Partido'].str.extract(regex)

#        Home       Away Score
# 0  América   Cruz Azul   0:0
# 1     Leon     América   2:0

# OR
df2 = df.join(df['Partido'].str.extract(regex))

# same a first output
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the regex documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You might use `rsplit` to get teams and score then `split` to get home and away following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Partido':['América - Cruz Azul 0:0','Leon - América 2:0']})
df[['Teams', 'Score']] = df.Partido.str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
df[['Home', 'Away']] = df.pop('Teams').str.split(' - ', expand=True)
print(df)
```

output

```
                   Partido Score     Home       Away
0  América - Cruz Azul 0:0   0:0  América  Cruz Azul
1       Leon - América 2:0   2:0     Leon    América
```

Note: I simplified input df for brevity sake. 1 in rsplit mean split once, i.e. at rightmost space. `.pop` does remove and return selected column, I use it as `Teams` is only temporary.

Answer (score 1):

One option with a split (regex):

```py
regex = r"(\d+:\d+)|\s+-\s+"
outcome = (df.Partido
             .str.split(regex, expand = True)
             .dropna(how ='all', axis = 1)
             .iloc[:, :-1]
           )

df[['Home', 'Away', 'Score']] = outcome

df

        Fecha                  Partido   Equipo    xG   xGA     Home        Away Score
0  2022-05-01  América - Cruz Azul 0:0  América  1.53  0.45  América  Cruz Azul    0:0
1  2022-05-01       Leon - América 2:0  América  1.70  0.35     Leon    América    2:0
```